# Minizinc large array dimension

Tags: minizinc

Am generating a large 2d array in Minizinc(for instance, 250000X300) as I'm searching for solutions in this array. However, Minizinc seems not to be able to handle such large arrays and keeps stop working. Is there any way to solve this problem so that I can still get my solutions??? - do I need to rewrite my code - but I still need this large array which contains the solutions.

Comment: Don't use Minizinc...

Comment: Really? But I thought it is powerful in solving optimization problems?

Comment: 75 million decision variables are just too many. I hope hey are binary and you can use Integer Linear Programming (not in Minizinc!) to solve that.

Comment: Is it during compilation that it runs out of memory? The other alternative is to try to decompose your problems and solve parts of it in different runs.